Snowflake JavaScript Stored Procedure Returns Success Despite Expected Failure
I've recently been experimenting with Snowflake's JavaScript stored procedures and encountered an unexpected behavior. I created a simple stored procedure as outlined in the Snowflake documentation here.
Here's the stored procedure I created:
create procedure broken()
      returns varchar not null
      language javascript
      as
      $$
      var result = "";
      try {
          snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "Invalid Command!;"} );
          result = "Succeeded";
          }
      catch (err)  {
          result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
          result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
          result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt; 
          }
      return result;
      $$
      ;

The purpose of this stored procedure is to deliberately fail by executing an invalid SQL command and then catch the error using a try-catch block.
When I call the stored procedure, it indeed returns the expected error message, indicating a failure:
call broken();

Output:
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| BROKEN                                                  |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
| Failed: Code: 1003                                      |
|   State: 42000                                          |
|   Message: SQL compilation error:                       |
| syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'Invalid'. |
| Stack Trace:                                            |
| Snowflake.execute, line 4 position 20                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------+

However, upon checking Snowflake's query history, I noticed that this procedure is marked as a successful run. This seems contradictory since the procedure explicitly aims to fail. I expect it to be tagged as a failed execution.
Could anyone shed some light on why Snowflake considers this a successful run despite the expected failure? Is there a different approach to handle such scenarios and ensure that failed stored procedure executions are correctly reflected in the query history? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

return a string "I HAVE FAILED" is a success, because it happened, where-as, actually failing:
create procedure actual_failure()
    returns varchar not null
    language javascript as
$$
    snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "Invalid Command!;"} );
    return "Succeeded";
$$
;

then
call actual_failure();

actually fails.


so what you are saying is that you can't have both try-catch and actual failure? Cuz eventually try catch returns a "success"

I have to also check if this actual failure works if you have a parent stor proc that calls many child stor procs. My aim is that the parent stor procs should fail if one of child stor procs fails.

yes, if you stop it failing, it didn't fail. BUT if you want to catch the failure, insert a row in a log table and then explode, to make the "whole procedure fail" you already have the parts to do that.

As others have mentioned, a "catch" handles the error so your Proc, as a whole, no longer errors. If you want your parent process to recognise that the Proc errored, even when you've handled the error in a "catch" block, then your "catch" needs to throw the error - using the "throw" command e.g. throw(result);

I have tried throw, it is still a success
